# How to read Freemarker Template files from src/main/resources folder?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, freemarker

How to access my freemarker template (*.ftl) files stored within my src/main/resources folder from my code (Spring Boot application) ?

I tried the following

```
freemarker.template.Configuration config = new Configuration();
configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/resources/templates/");
```

and getting the following exception

```
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "my-template.ftl".
```

Comment: You shouldn't actually need to do nothing if you use the out-of-the-box Spring configuration. As Spring boot configures free marker including the resolvers for you.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The root of the classpath is `src/main/resources`, change the path to

```
configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/templates/");
```

Comment: but if we run the code from jar file ,how to modify the code to adapter it ? like : java -jar freemarker.jar , in this jar file the templates folder in located in the root of this jar package .

Comment: give more guys the idea here:                                                                                          new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass().getClassLoader(), "templates")                                      new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass(), "/templates")

Comment: @AlterHu, ideally you should put src/main/resources inside your jar file.

Comment: @Biscuit128 totally agreed with your comment :D

Answer (score 6):

I was facing "freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name..." issue.
My code was correct but I forgot to include /templates/ directory in pom.xml. So below code fixed the issue for me. I hope this helps.

```java
 AppConfig.java :

    @Bean(name="freemarkerConfiguration")
    public freemarker.template.Configuration getFreeMarkerConfiguration() {
        freemarker.template.Configuration config = new freemarker.template.Configuration(freemarker.template.Configuration.getVersion());
        config.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/templates/");
        return config;
    }

 EmailSenderServiceImpl.java:

    @Service("emailService")
    public class EmailSenderServiceImpl implements EmailSenderService 
    {
        @Autowired
        private Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;

        public String geFreeMarkerTemplateContent(Map<String, Object> dataModel, String templateName)
        {
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                content.append(FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(templateName), dataModel));
                return content.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception exception) {
                logger.error("Exception occured while processing freeMarker template: {} ", exception.getMessage(), exception);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }


 pom.xml :

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>templates/*.ftl</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>templates/*.ftl</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
```